# iOS sdk - UIImagePickerController without Popover

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

My question may be lame, because i`m new to iOS development, but anyway...
Now i have code that shows me images from device into popover (using UIImagePickerController). How can i (if i can) show those images into UITableViewController or something like it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIImagePickerControllers can only be presented in popovers on iPad, trying to present one otherwise will result in an assertion failure stating just that. To get at user photos and display them in a custom way you should look into the [Assets Library Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730).